# some arabic words in beamer, babel xelatex problem!

Tags: xetex, babel, arabic

How to insert some arabic words in a beamer presentation using the babel package and xelatex?
I have tried the following code but the arab words are not displayed!

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[main=english]{babel}

\babelprovide[import]{arabic}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}{Amiri}

\title{My Beamer Presentation with somme arabic words}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{First Frame}
  Some arabic words:
  \foreignlanguage{arabic}{كلمات باللغة
  العربية
  } 
that  aren't displayed!
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default family in beamer is `sf`, not `rm`. Here is the MWE with some additional changes (which apply to this MWE):

- Don’t use `main`. Rely on the default behaviour: the last language in `\usepackage` is the main one.
- No need to load `fontspec` explicitly.
- Set the `bidi` mode. I’ve chosen `bidi=default`, which for a few words is usually better than `bidi=bidi`, which loads a huge machinery with a lot of unnecessary changes for simple cases like this.
- Loading `arabic` with `\selectlanguage` for short texts isn’t necessary.
- And, of course, define the `sf` font instead of `rm`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[bidi=default, english]{babel}
\babelfont[arabic]{sf}{Amiri}

\title{My Beamer Presentation with somme arabic words}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{First Frame}
  Some arabic words:
  \foreignlanguage{arabic}{كلمات باللغة العربية} 
  that are displayed!
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! thank you! @javier